# POST call to Lumen API not working on production server

Tags: php, laravel, api, nginx, lumen

I have this strange issue where making a POST request to my production server results in the response I have defined for the GET request to the same route. POST works fine for my local development server. Here's the code I'm using:

routes/web.php:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return "Lumen is running.";
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function($router)
{
    $router->get('message','MessageController@index');    
    $router->post('message','MessageController@create');
});
```

So, when I send a POST request to productionurl.com/v1/message, create() isn't executed, but when I send the exact same request to developmenturl.com/v1/message, it is.

I've tried deleting all routes but the POST one, this results in a MethodNotAllowedHttpException on the production server.

I've setup PHP7.0, Nginx and MongoDB manually on a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.

Development server is a Homestead VM with PHP7.1 and Nginx, with MongoDB running on my host computer.